# How to specify Nuget schema?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, nuget

I have two projects in the same solution that I use to create nuget packages. When I take each of those packages and unzip it to find the generated nuspec, I find they are each targetting different xml schemas.

Package A:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
```

Package B:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
```

This is a problem because my build server wants to nuget push them with nuget version 1.7 (and I can't upgrade it) so will only push package A.

How can I force package B to target the same schema as A?

Additional info:
Package A targets .Net 4.0
Package B targets .Net 3.5
I'm packing with nuget 2.8 locally and can confirm that the same command generates a different schema version:

```
nuget pack xxx.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -OutputDirectory c:\nuget\MyPackageLibrary -verbosity detailed
```

(I have a corresponding xxx.nuspec file that gets used for meta data)

I've tried specifying no schema in either .nuspec file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
<metadata>
```

and I've tried specifying:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd"> <metadata>
```

But it has no effect on the .nuspec I find when I unzip the packaged artifact.

Comment: due to my limited comments credits this comes as an answer: Here is a list of schemas and what they contain: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/PackageCreation/Authoring/ManifestSchemaUtility.cs @Matt-ward already pointed to that file, but it has since been moved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot upgrade the build server's version of NuGet then I would just use the same version so the same schema version is generated in the NuGet package.

Looking at the NuGet source code the version of the schema used depends on the feature set used by the NuGet package. For example, if your NuGet package uses an XDT transform then it will use schema version 4 namespace:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd
```

This version 4 namespace is not included in NuGet 1.7. XDT transforms were included in NuGet 2.6.

In NuGet 2.8.7 there are two locations where the schema version is determined.

- [PackageBuilder](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.8.7/src/Core/Authoring/PackageBuilder.cs#L284-L299)
- [ManifestSchemaUtility](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/2.8.7/src/Core/Authoring/ManifestVersionUtility.cs#L25-L52)

  - Schema version 4: Dependency contents and tools with target framework defined
  - Schema version 4: Dependencies with target framework defined.
  - Schema version 5: Assembly references with target framework defined
  - Schema version 6: XDT transforms

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can determine the features that belong to each namespace?

Comment: You can look at the NuGet source code. This information is not documented anywhere else as far as I am aware. I have updated the answer with more information.

Comment: Brilliant. This works great. We're still stuck on an older version of NuGet. In our case, simply excluding the <releaseNotes> element caused the correct schema version to be included. Thanks :)